# jQuery - Keep animation state

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm creating a painting application in JavaScript, but am having a little issue with one element. I have a row of coloured circles that represent the different colours that can be used in the application.

When the user hovers over them, the borderTopLeftRadius property is animated. When the mouse is moved away, they revert back to the initial state:

```
$('.swatch').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ borderTopLeftRadius: 40 }, 200)
});

$('.swatch').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ borderTopLeftRadius: 100 }, 100)
});
```

My issue is keeping the borderTopLeftRadius  proprerty changed when the user clicks on a colour - when it is selected. I have tried:

```
$('.swatch').click(function() {
    $(this).css("border-top-left-radius", "40px");
});
```

but this collides with the mouseout function. Is there a way to keep the changed property when a swatch is selected, but still allow the others to be animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class for the active state:

```
$('.swatch').on({
    click: function() {
        $('.swatch').not(this).removeClass('active')
                    .animate({ borderTopLeftRadius: 100 }, 200);
        $(this).addClass('active').css({ borderTopLeftRadius: 40 });
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
        if (! $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            $(this).animate({ borderTopLeftRadius: 40 }, 200)
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if (! $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            $(this).animate({ borderTopLeftRadius: 100 }, 200)
        }
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UQY8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class named `active` to the item that you click, then check for this in your `mouseout` event. You can also remove this class when it is clicked again.

Example : <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/Jsr2f/)</kbd>

```
$('.swatch').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ borderTopLeftRadius: 40 }, 200)
});

$('.swatch').mouseout(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).animate({ borderTopLeftRadius: 100 }, 100)
    }
});

$('.swatch').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).css("border-top-left-radius", "40px");
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you try something like?;

```
$('.swatch').click(function() {
    $(this).css("border-top-left-radius", "40px");
    $(this).on('mouseout', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I combine jQuery and HTML animations is that where possible I try to do all my animations using CSS3 by simply adding a 'animate' or 'active' class to the target. You'll find that doing animations in this manor should prevent headaches like you're currently having and avoids unnecessarily bloating your markup.